# Getting an error when querying to Opportunity Object: Variable does not exist: ContactId

Tags: apex

This is the function that is being called on `beforeUpdate` event:

```apex
private static void validateContactRole() {
    for( Opportunity newOpportunityData : (Opportunity[])Trigger.new ) { 
        if( Trigger.isUpdate ) {
            if( newOpportunityData.StageName != 'Preliminary Account Review' ) {
                // Check classification first
                List<String> classificationsToExclude = new List<String>();
                classificationsToExclude.add('National Government');
                classificationsToExclude.add('US Civilian');
                classificationsToExclude.add('US DOD');                
                List<Account> oppAccount = [Select Classification__c from Account Where Id = :newOpportunityData.AccountId];
                for( Account acc : oppAccount ) {
                    Boolean accountIsExcluded = false;
                    for( String cf : classificationsToExclude ) {
                        if( cf == acc.Classification__c ) {
                            accountIsExcluded = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if( !accountIsExcluded ) {
                        List<Contact> contacts = [Select Primary_Contact__c from Contact Where Id = :newOpportunityData.ContactId];
                        if( contacts.isEmpty() ) {
                           newOpportunityData.addError('Contact Role is Required. Please enter value in the Contact Role Section.'); 
                        } else {
                           Boolean hasPrimary = false;
                           for(Contact cc : contacts) {
                               if( cc.Primary_Contact__c == true ) {
                                   hasPrimary = true;
                               }
                           }
                           if ( !hasPrimary ) {
                               newOpportunityData.addError('No Primary Contact was set. Please set a Primary Contact.');        
                           } else {
                               if( newOpportunityData.Opp_ContactRoleCount__c == null || newOpportunityData.Opp_ContactRoleCount__c < 1 ) {
                                   newOpportunityData.addError('The [Opp ContactRoleCount] field must be greater than zero.'); 
                               }
                           }
                        }
                    }
                }          
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error preview:

[image]

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
I stand corrected. The right versions are 45 and 46 not 4.5 or 4.6

Duhhh! It's the API version! I was using 4.5 and according here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm

I must use 4.6 and higher.
Thanks to Andriy.

[image]

Comment: It's 46, not 4.6. Salesforce hasn't had a fractional API number since like 1.5.